# How could I set up the height of cell to auto with Python xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I would like to put the variable length text to an Excel file - some text are shorten, and another are longer. These cells are one above the other, so the width of cells are equal.

I'm trying to do this:

```
sheet.row(rownr).height = 0
```

with combination if

```
sheet.row(rownr).height_mismatch = True
```

The first line produces a higher line than the "normal", but when the text wrapped more that 2 lines, the height doesn't follow, so the text aren't showed.

What would be the right way?

Thanks:

a.

Comment: It kinda works for me with the default settings (not setting height and height_mismatch, but 'align: on' (easyxf)/ Alignment.WRAP_AT_RIGHT (XFStyle by hand). Not as reliable as I'd wish when viewing with libreoffice.